# Entity framework Code First with Migrations Cascade Delete is not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a Code First Model and I'm trying to delete all rows which was referenced to a certain ID, the problem is, it was working before I use Migrations. this is my Code :

```
var query = context.user.Include(p => p.area).
                    Include(p => p.city).Include(p => p.city.state).
                    Include(p => p.city.state.country).
                    Include(p => p.favorites).Include(p => p.ads).FirstOrDefault(a => a.id_user == result);

                context.user.Remove(query);
                context.Entry(query).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                context.SaveChanges();
```

It just delete the user table, not all!

Answer (score 0):

Either turn cascade delete on for user so when it is deleted, all its children will be deleted as well. Like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<user>()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

If you do not want that, you can use `RemoveRange` like this:

```
context.user.RemoveRange(query);
```

Or you can loop through each child and delete them individually like this:

```
foreach (var record in context.user.area)
{
    user.area.Remove(record);
}
```

And last thing, you can remove one of your includes since you do not need it.

```
var query = context.user.Include(p => p.area).
                    Include(p => p.city.state.country).
                    Include(p => p.favorites).Include(p => p.ads).FirstOrDefault(a => a.id_user == result);
```

**EDIT 1**

I am not sure what kind of relationships you have setup between your entities. `WillCascadeOnDelete(true)` should delete the children when the parent is deleted. Here is an example:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>() 
    .HasRequired(t => t.Department) 
    .WithMany(t => t.Courses) 
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.DepartmentID) 
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

What the above is saying is this: `Course` must have a `Department`, and a `Department` has many courses, and a `Course` has a foreign-key named `DepartmentID`. When a `Department` is deleted, cascade the deletion: meaning delete all the courses (children) of this department. Here the relationship is one department can have many courses: one to many.

If a child object has a non-nullable foreign-key then EF will delete the child when the parent is deleted: cascade on delete will be set by default. If the child can have a nullable foreign key, then the child will not be deleted when the parent is deleted.

So from the above we can tell that the deletion strategy EF uses depends on how you have setup your model.

Your query returns one `user`. Therefore, if you want to delete all the children, they will be deleted automatically if you have built your model that way.

If you have not, then delete the children one by one. If a user has one child of `area` then do this:

```
context.user.area.Remove(query.user.area);
```

If a `user` has many `area` then use the foreach strategy I have shown above.

Comment: Hi, the First one does'n work, it says that `WillCascadeOnDelete` doesnt' exist.. The second I had ti change to Where from FirstOrDefault, because was showing a Error "cannot convert user to ICollection"!

Comment: I am not sure why `WillCascadeOnDelete` is complaining for you. What EF version are you using? Did any of the suggestions work for you or none of them?

Comment: Entity 6, the last one worked, but erase all the datas. That thing is not working after i use Migrations, don't know why.. When I use the `foreach`, user.area. you mean query.area?

Comment: Yes if you only want to delete that specific one then use query.area. You would do that for all children you want to delete.

Comment: the problem is, the query is using a condition of FirstOrDefault, so the method Remove will not appear !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130167/discussion-between-nathiel-paulino-and-codingyoshi).